# "No operator matches the given name and argument types" when trying to get sum of two columns by rows in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

eg:

```
select sum(column1+column2) from mytable group by id;
```

but i getting error

```
No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts
```

Comment: Looks like the data type for column1 or column2 is incorrect for addition. Post your table DDL.

Comment: In future post the whole error text. In your case it could to looks like `ERROR:  operator does not exist: text + text LINE 1: ... t(x,y) as (values('a'::text, 'b'::text)) select x+y from t; HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.`

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO.

You are performing sum and add to columns that most likely aren't numeric. Check the data type of `column1` and `column2`, and in case they are `text` or `varchar` cast them like this:

```
SELECT id, sum(column1::INTEGER+column2::INTEGER) 
FROM mytable GROUP BY id;
```

Sample

```
WITH  mytable (id, column1, column2) AS (
  VALUES (1,'1','2'),(1,'2','2'),(2,'3','3')
)
SELECT id, sum(column1::INTEGER+column2::INTEGER) 
FROM mytable GROUP BY id;

 id | ?column? 
----+----------
  1 |        7
  2 |        6
(2 Zeilen)
```